# Combobox doesn't open popup if MouseArea is above it

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols

I have a listview with a delegate that has MouseArea covering the whole of a delegate. In that MouseArea's onClick slot I specifically set

```
mouse.accepted = false
```

but the Combobox from QtQuick.Controls 1.4 that lives in that delegate still refuses to open its popup on clicks. I've tested that combobox should receive the click with:

```
ComboBox {
                id: cbChapters
                model: chapters
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        mouse.accepted = false
                        console.log("arrived")
                    }
                }
            }
```

And the click events **do** arrive into this inner mouse area, just not into the combobox itself it seems... what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: 
Problem seems to be that MouseArea automatically accepts **Pressed** events and in the Combobox code itself there's this:

```
onPressed: {
    if (!Settings.hasTouchScreen)
        popup.toggleShow()
}
onClicked: {
    if (Settings.hasTouchScreen)
        popup.toggleShow()
}
```

So it seems like **Clicked** requires *touchscreen* to open the popup(which is not present on the desktop, obviously)
This leaves only **Pressed** to open the popup, but it's being suppressed at the uppermost MouseArea as it is not a composed event and propagateComposedEvents does nothing for it.

The solution could be :

1) to go through your mouse area chain and in each one of them set:

```
onPressed: {
mouse.accepted = false
}
```

2) call popup directly in "clicked" handler

```
ComboBox {
id: cbChapters
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    propagateComposedEvents: true
    onClicked: {
        cbChapters.__popup.toggleShow()
    }
}
}
```